# PowerShell script issue operators

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to use PowerShell to detect Intel NIC drivers, prior to deploying the updated drivers.  I changed my script a bit to troubleshoot, to make sure I am capturing the correct driver versions, and eventually verifying proper use of operators (which I may not be).

```
#Change $DeployVersion to the driver version being deployed
#Change $INTELNICMODEL to the model of Intel NIC
#=======================================================
$DeployVersion = “12.15.31.0″
$INTELNICMODEL = “82579LM”

#Get IntelNIC Driver Version from Win32_PnPSignedDriver
$CurrentlyInstalledDriverVersion = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver |   Where-Object {$_.deviceclass -match “NET” -and $_.devicename -like “*$INTELNICMODEL*” -and $_.driverversion} | Select driverversion
Write $CurrentlyInstalledDriverVersion.driverversion
Write $DeployVersion
If ($CurrentlyInstalledVersion.driverversion -lt $DeployVersion)
{Write “need to update driver”}
else
{Write “driver is current”}
```

**From a computer with `$CurrentlyInstalledDriverVersion = $DeployVersion`**

OUTPUT

```
PS> .\testIntelNIC.ps1
12.15.31.0
12.15.31.0
need to update driver
```

Clearly, this is not right, so some testing…

change `-lt` to `-gt`

OUTPUT

```
PS> .\testIntelNIC.ps1
12.15.31.0
12.15.31.0
driver is current
```

…and then try `-eq`

OUTPUT

```
PS> .\testIntelNIC.ps1
12.15.31.0
12.15.31.0
driver is current
```

**Then from a computer where `$CurrentlyInstalledDriverVersion < $DeployVersion`**

OUTPUT

```
PS> .\testIntelNIC.ps1
12.6.47.1
12.15.31.0
need to update driver
```

..which looks good, but…

Change `-lt` to `-gt`

OUTPUT

```
PS> .\testIntelNIC.ps1
12.6.47.1
12.15.31.0
driver is current
```

Am I using the operators incorrectly? Or the if/else?

Comment: `″` is not valid double quote character in PowerShell, so your script should not work at all as it have syntax error. `$CurrentlyInstalledVersion` and `$CurrentlyInstalledDriverVersion` are different variables, as them have different names.

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy in my post.  Should only be $CurrentlyInstalledVersion in my script.

Answer (score 3):

String comparisons don't know anything about the inner structure of your version strings. Cast the strings to [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects and you'll be able to do proper comparisons. Note that you need to expand the `DriverVersion` property for the conversion to work.

```
[Version]$DeployVersion = "12.15.31.0"
...
[Version]$CurrentlyInstalledDriverVersion = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver |
    Where-Object {
        $_.deviceclass -match "NET" -and
        $_.devicename -like "*$INTELNICMODEL*" -and
        $_.driverversion
    } | Select -Expand driverversion
```

Comment: Thank you for advising me about Version.  This reference should help me understand what I need.